# Can I Install Digikam without installing most of KDE?

Tags: package-management, kde, digikam

I'd like to transition from F-Spot to Digikam because I fully believe it to be a better application for my needs, as somebody who takes and post-processes a *lot* of photos. The problem is... Well, I think the `apt-get` output says it better than I can:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed
  akonadi-server digikam digikam-data dolphin kdebase-bin kdebase-data kdebase-runtime kdebase-runtime-data kdegraphics-libs-data kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins
  kdepim-runtime kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdoctools kfind kipi-plugins kipi-plugins-common konqueror konqueror-nsplugins kubuntu-debug-installer libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4
  libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libattica0 libboost-program-options1.42.0 libclucene0ldbl libgps19 libiodbc2 libkabc4 libkatepartinterfaces4
  libkcal4 libkcmutils4 libkdcraw9 libkde3support4 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkexiv2-9 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4
  libkio5 libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkonq5-templates libkonq5a libkonqsidebarplugin4a
  libkparts4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksane0 libktexteditor4 libkutils4 libmailtransport4 libmarblewidget11 libmicroblog4 libnepomuk4
  libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqjson0 libqt4-sql-mysql libsolid4 libsoprano4
  libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libthreadweaver4 libvirtodbc0 marble-data marble-plugins mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 ntrack-module-libnl-0 oxygen-icon-theme
  plasma-scriptengine-declarative plasma-scriptengine-javascript qapt-batch shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin
  virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
0 upgraded, 105 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 80.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 250 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Now, I'm not adverse to installing things like Qt. I'm not even against installing a lot of packages.... **But Digikam wants to install all the packages.** Why does it want MySQL ?! I thought it used SQLite! Konqueror!? Dolphin?! These are hefty applications by themselves... How could an image browser/editor need this much of KDE?

Is there a way I can trim this down so I'm not installing every package and its brother?

Comment: `digikam` depends on `kdepim-runtime` which depends on `akonadi-server` which depends on the MySQL server + client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get --no-install-recommends install digikam` provides a slightly better outlook:

```
0 upgraded, 82 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 69.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 211 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

It still includes MySQL but Konqueror and Dolphin aren't in the list.